# list images in gridview and show border on image click

Tags: android, gridview, checkbox, imageview

i've created a simple image picker,in the grid view i've added 2 views:
imageview and checkbox.
so i tried to set border around the image when its clicked,but other images get border two(even if i didnt clicked on them),heres the activity:

```
public class Media extends ActionBarActivity {
private int count;
private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
private String[] selectedImg;
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
ArrayList<String> rtnSelectedImg = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.media);

//ActionBar settings :
try {
    ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
    Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
    if(menuKeyField != null) {
      menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
      menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
     } 
} catch (Exception ex) {}
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
      MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
      null,null, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
    this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];
    this.selectedImg = new String[this.count];
    this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];

//Adding the images to grid :
    for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
          getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
        selectedImg[i]= imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }

    GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    imagecursor.close();    

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.media, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
    finish();
}
else if (id == R.id.done) {

     Intent main = new Intent(this, Main.class);
 main.putStringArrayListExtra("media_lst",rtnSelectedImg);
 startActivity(main);
     //finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
//Image Adapter Class
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.media_item, parent,false);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);               
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
    //  holder.checkbox.setId(position);
    //  holder.imageview.setId(position);
        holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {             
            public void onClick(View v) {         holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);

            //  int id = holder.checkbox.getId();
            //  int ids = holder.imageview.getId();
                if (holder.checkbox.isChecked()){
              rtnSelectedImg.remove(selectedImg[position]); 
                  holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
                    thumbnailsselection[position] = false;
                  holder.imageview.setBackgroundResource(0);

                } else {    
        rtnSelectedImg.add(selectedImg[position]); 
                holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
                  thumbnailsselection[position] = true;
              holder.imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.media_row_border);

                }
                if(!rtnSelectedImg.isEmpty()){
                  getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Selected "+rtnSelectedImg.size());
                }else{
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Media");
                }
            } 
        });
        // i = new AQuery(getApplicationContext());
        holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);
        holder.id = position;
        return convertView;
    }
}
class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageview;
    CheckBox checkbox;
    int id;
}
}
```

Comment: use an xml selector as the background to the item view.

Comment: holder.imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.media_row_border);
- link to xml shape ..

Comment: Check out this question, seems to be similar to me http://stackoverflow.com/q/25673713/1671933

Comment: My question is - why other images get border even if i didnt click on them

Comment: I have done a similar thing before and i used only xml, the selector was the android.background(@drawable/selector) for the item view, sorry i wasn't clear on where i was suggesting you put the selector.

Comment: no worries jesson,thats happend:)